# Express $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ in Terms of $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$, and Their Derivatives

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are linearly independent solutions of the differential equation $$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$ I wish to express $P(x)$, $Q(x)$ in terms of $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$, and their derivatives. I know that by Abel's formula, the Wronskian for this equation is represented by: $$W=ke^{-\int P(x)dx}$$ where in our case, $k \neq 0$. We also know that: $$W\left[y_1(x),y_2(x)\right]=y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_2(x)y_1'(x)$$ Setting these two equations equal to each other, we have that: $$\int P(x)dx=-\ln\left[\frac1k\left(y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_2(x)y_1'(x)\right)\right] \implies P(x)=\frac{y_2(x)y_1''(x)-y_1(x)y_2''(x)}{y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_2(x)y_1'(x)}$$ This process has been rather straight-forward, but I am now having trouble representing $Q(x)$. Is there an adaptation of Abel's formula for $Q(x)$, or if I may represent it using what I have already found, how might I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Q(x) = -\frac{y'' + P(x) y'}{y}$

sub in what you have for $P(x)$ and $y$ can be either $y_1$ or $y_2$